# Compare two base64 image strings in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I would like to compare the two following base64 strings to ensure that a photo is uploaded as expected. How would I do that? This my code below, I currently get the error message:

```
You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

  > text
```

This is my code:

```
it('should allow the user to select a navbar component and replace a logo', () => {
  cy.getIframeBody('builder-showcase').find('[data-cy="navbar-component"]').eq(0).click();
  cy.getIframeBody('builder-showcase').find('[data-cy="navbar-logo-image"]').eq(0).click();
  cy.get('[data-cy="builder-sidebar-menu-select-image-navbar"]').eq(0).click();
  const navbarLogoImage = 'navbar-logo-image.png';
  cy.fixture(navbarLogoImage).then(originalLogoImage => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="image-file-input"]').attachFile(navbarLogoImage);
    cy.get('[data-cy="image-alt-text"]')
      .clear()
      .type('Twitter logo image');
    cy.get('.source-image').invoke('attr', 'src')
      .then(uploadedLogoImage => {
        expect(uploadedLogoImage).to.have.text(originalLogoImage);
      })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chai chainer `to.have.text` verifies that an element (DOM or JQuery) contains the expected text. Your `uploadedLogoImage` is a string. You should then use a chainer that will work with a string like:

```
expect(uploadedLogoImage).to.eq(originalLogoImage);
```

or

```
expect(uploadedLogoImage).to.contain(originalLogoImage);
```

or with `should()`, you can query the element directly:

```
cy.get('.source-image').should('have.attr', 'src', originalLogoImage);
```

Hint: instead of using `eq(0)`, you may also use `first()` which gives a better readability.